# How do I make code inside of a C# method act on a timer?

Tags: c#, timer

```
 static void DoThing()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Do thing 1");

        // After a delay, I want it to do thing 2

        Console.WriteLine("Do thing 2");
    }
```

Basically want something like this. When the method is called, I want it to do the first thing right away, but then after a set amount of time has passed, do the second thing.

Is it possible to do it this way, or am I missing something?

Comment: The preferred contemporary way is `await Task.Delay();`

Comment: In the case where you aren't using async/await tasks, you can also use Thread.Sleep

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Task.Delay()`:

```cs
static async Task DoThing(int delayTimeInMilliseconds)
{
   Console.WriteLine("Do thing 1");

   await Task.Delay(delayTimeInMilliseconds);

   Console.WriteLine("Do thing 2");
}
```